# Jquery Dialog not loading for multiple time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First time the dialog get loaded properly and second time throw error

> $(...).dialog is not a function error.

Below is the code

HTML :

```
<div id="targetDiv" style="display:none"></div>
```

JAVAscript

```
$().ready(function(){
 var formName = "xyz";

    $("[href*="+'"'+formName+'"'+"]").each(function(i,v) {

        $.get("<jsp_path>", function(data) {
              // Save jQuery to a variable in case the loaded page includes its own jQuery.
            var _$ = window.$,
                _jQuery = window.jQuery,
                _$CQ = window.$CQ;

            // Insert the page content.
            $(v).after(data);

            // Restore our original jQuery variables.
            window.$ = _$;
            window.jQuery = _jQuery;
            window.$CQ = _$CQ;

             $(v).click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                 callScript(linkText);
                  });

             });
        });
```

function callScript(url) {

```
var url = url;
var $modalFormDialog = $('#targetDiv').dialog({
        dialogClass : 'custom-modal-1',
        height : 'auto',
        width : 650,
        position : 'top',
        modal : true,
        autoOpen : false
});
$modalFormDialog.dialog('open');
$modalFormDialog.load(url);
$('#targetDiv').delegate('.modal-close', "click", function(e) {
    $modalFormDialog.dialog('close');
    return false;
});
```

});

Comment: format your code please.. when you submit a question you can actually see the preview before submiting :)

Comment: @dvenkatsagar, if she didn't add jquery ui then how jquery code will work at first time?

Comment: Yes, Im sorry, didnt read the question properly ....

Comment: I dont see any problems in the code(just changed delegate to on) : https://jsfiddle.net/etq0khze/

Comment: most probably a JS library conflict ..can you show all js files you included

Comment: @Aditi the code you provided works well 2, 3 and n times, without page refreshing. Let me know how you invoke modal dialog.

Comment: @YoYo   below the url I want to load in dialog     JSP : 

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div class="modal-form-display" id="form-display" style="">
 <span id="modal-close" class="modal-close">Close</span>
</div>

Comment: @dvenkatsagar delegate is because I am making the dialog dynamically, on is not working for me :(

Comment: With the updated question, I dont find any problem with your logic, but there are some places where I think its best you change the code. I will give answer. Kindly check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Include jquery library only once .. Do these changes

```
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>  
    <div class="modal-form-display" id="form-display" style=""> 
    <span id="modal-close" class="modal-close">Close</span> 

    </div>
```

Comment: why all jquery files ??  include those jquery library files which are required

Comment: i have lot of jquery include on the page, this is one of them.

Comment: Is there any way to remove the conflict, $.noConflict() is also not working? :(

Answer (score 0):

Well when looking at the code you have given, I dont find any problems in the logic that you are trying to implement, but I think you need to change your JS a little like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var formName = "xyz";

    $("[href*='"+formName+"']").each(function(i,v) {

        $.get("<jsp_path>", function(data) {
              // Save jQuery to a variable in case the loaded page includes its own jQuery.

            // Dont do this, even if the jquery changes, most of the core functionality should work.
            //var _$ = window.$,
            //    _jQuery = window.jQuery,
            //    _$CQ = window.$CQ;

            // Insert the page content.
            $(this).after(data);

            // Restore our original jQuery variables.
            //window.$ = _$;
            //window.jQuery = _jQuery;
            //window.$CQ = _$CQ;

             $(this).on("click",function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                 callScript(linkText);
             });

        });
    });
});

var callScript = function(url){
    var $modalFormDialog = $('#targetDiv').dialog({
        dialogClass : 'custom-modal-1',
        height : 'auto',
        width : 650,
        position : 'top',
        modal : true,
        autoOpen : false
    });
    $modalFormDialog.dialog('open');
    $modalFormDialog.load(url);
    $('#targetDiv').on('click','.modal-close', function(e) {
      $modalFormDialog.dialog('close');
    });
}
```

Hope it helps. But if it doesnt work, I think you are missing something, maybe loading your libraries correctly or something. Just check it out and see if it works.